# Is there any function (change Tuple to Array) or (sum Array by key)?

Tags: clickhouse

Q1 and Q2 is same Question on different sides.
if data store as tuple(key, value), any SQL can get same result?

```
(1,3)(2,5)(4,7)
(1,3)(2,5)(3,4)
(2,3)(7,5)(10,4)
```

Q1: sumMap can change Array to Tuple,but how to change Tuple to Array?

```sql
select sumMap(a, b) from (
select array(1,2,4) as a, array(3,5,7) as b
union all
select array(1,2,3) as a, array(3,5,4) as b
union all
select array(2,7,10) as a, array(3,5,4) as b);

│ ([1,2,3,4,7,10],[6,13,4,7,5,4]) │
```

Error SQL:

```sql
select sumMap(a, b).[0], sumMap(a, b).[1] from tbl

[1,2,3,4,7,10]   [6,13,4,7,5,4]
```

Q2: How to sum Array by key, like sumMap?

```sql
select array(1,2,4) as a, array(3,5,7) as b
union all
select array(1,2,3) as a, array(3,5,4) as b
union all
select array(2,7,10) as a, array(3,5,4) as b

│ [1,2,4] │ [3,5,7] │
│ [2,7,10]│ [3,5,4] │
│ [1,2,3] │ [3,5,4] │
```

Error SQL:

```sql
select sumBykey(a, a), sumBykey(b, a).key2 from tbl

[1,2,3,4,7,10]   [6,13,4,7,5,4]
```

Answer (score 2):

It needs to use [tuple access operators](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/operators/#access-operators).

```sql
SELECT
    sumMap(a, b) AS summap,
    summap.1 AS a1,
    summap.2 AS a2
FROM
(
    SELECT [1, 2, 4] AS a, [3, 5, 7] AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [1, 2, 3] AS a, [3, 5, 4] AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [2, 7, 10] AS a, [3, 5, 4] AS b
)

/* Result:
    ┌─summap──────────────────────────┬─a1─────────────┬─a2─────────────┐
    │ ([1,2,3,4,7,10],[6,13,4,7,5,4]) │ [1,2,3,4,7,10] │ [6,13,4,7,5,4] │
    └─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘
*/
```

At this moment [sumMap](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#agg_functions-summap) supports only numeric keys-values.  Use hash for keys other types:

```sql
SELECT
    sumMap(arrayMap(x -> xxHash32(x), a), b) AS summap,
    summap.1 AS a1,
    summap.2 AS a2
FROM
(
    SELECT ['1', '2', '4'] AS a, [3, 5, 7] AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ['1', '2', '3'] AS a, [3, 5, 4] AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ['2', '7', '10'] AS a, [3, 5, 4] AS b
)

/* Result:
┌─summap─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─a1────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─a2─────────────┐
│ ([205742900,548432130,1150380693,1842982710,2632741828,3068971186],[13,5,4,7,4,6]) │ [205742900,548432130,1150380693,1842982710,2632741828,3068971186] │ [13,5,4,7,4,6] │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: `sumMap` does not seem to accept string keys (using Clickhouse 19.13). Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: @Backlin i extended the answer

Comment: In my case I do have to preserve the original keys though. Ultimately I got it working with the method you suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204033/840460), i.e. `flatten(groupArray(a)) as str_keys`, `arrayEnumerateDense(keys) as int_keys` (alternatively you could hash here), then `arrayReduce('sumMap', [int_keys], ...)` and finally lookup the original keys using `arrayFirst`. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the "intermediate columns" from appearing in the output? E.g. if the user only cares about `a1, a2` is there a way to remove `summap`?

Comment: @Backlin I glad to help you. To hide unused-columns just use nested query like this: *SELECT a1, a2 FROM (SELECT sumMap(arrayMap(x -> xxHash32(x), a), b) AS summap,  summap.1 AS a1,  summap.2 AS a2 ...)*.